# What is the Difference b/w addObject:dictionary and addObject:[dictionary copy] to an NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to set some values to my NSMutableDictionary inside a loop and assigning the dictionary values to an NSMutableArray each time like below,

```
for(int i=0;i<=lastObj;i++){
[mutableDict setValue:[valuesArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"Name"];
[mutableDict setValue:[uniqueArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"SSN"];
//......then
**[mutableArray addObject:mutableDict];**/*not working perfectly all values s replaced by final mutableDict values (duplicate values)*/
```

but

```
**[mutableArray addObject:[mutableDict copy]];**/* Working Correctly !!! */
}
```

inside loop in each iteration new values is assigned to mutableDictionary and whenever i say just addObject my mutableArray is getting all duplicate values but whenever i say addObject:[mutableDict **copy**], array is getting correct unique values without any duplicates, i don't know what the difference the compiler feels when i say copy, can anybody tell me the difference in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[mutableArray addObject:mutableDict];
```

keeps on adding mutableDict to mutableArray. adding the object doesnt create a new memory location, it points to the same memory. so when u set the values of mutableDict, it gets reflected in all added objects as they refer to same memory location.

copy creates a new memory location and adds the object removing the above scenario.

to avoid this u can add

```
for(int i=0;i<=lastObj;i++){
NSMutableDictionary * mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary new]; //create new memory location
[mutableDict setValue:[valuesArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"Name"];
[mutableDict setValue:[uniqueArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"SSN"];

[mutableArray addObject:mutableDict];
[mutableDict release]; //release 
}
```

hope this helps u. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code block, its clear you are allocating mutableDict outside your for loop. Hence When you say below statement inside the for loop, basically you are passing the same object for addition to mutalbeArray.

[mutableArray addObject:mutableDict];

addObject doesnt allocate any memory for objects, but it uses the same object passed and just sends "retain" message to increase the reference count. Since you are passing the same object within the for loop, mutalbeArray would contain the references to same object.

In case of copy say,

[mutableArray addObject:[mutableDict copy]];

the copy message sent to mutableDict returns a new copy which is then passed addObject. Hence every iteration in the forloop passes a new object(due to copy) to addObject.

Also note these following

1. Copy creates a new object, it should be later released, but your code is not releasing it. This will lead to memory leak.
2. Copy creates immutable object, hence you should probably use mutableCopy instead if you want objects added to mutableArray to be modified.